# Input form that only accepts specific number of length in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have an array of number [12,14,20]. I want this number to be the specific length inside my input form. so for example the user can only input number with the length of 12,14 and 20 else it will prompt an error. so far i only found minlength and maxlength method but it does not solve my problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: One way is to add custom validator and check if `control.value?.length` exists in the array?

Comment: is there any way for me to use keyup instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Reactive form. I suggest you can write a custom validator

```
export function MaxLengthValidator(arr: number[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
           return arr.some(el => el === control.value.toString().length) ? null : { 'LengthNotMatch' : { value: control.value } };
    };
}
```

You can check the simple demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-wm8vjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fname.validator.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: do you know how to do it using keyup method?